# Running Python script through Crontab, but SQL database not updating

Tags: python, sql, database, cron

I have a Python script to update a SQL database. When I run the script on Terminal manually, everything works fine. But when I run this on a crontab, the database is not getting updated.

Comment: Make sure your code is calling `commit`

Comment: check the log file